# SHIFT + RETURN keys on keyboard to go to new line

Tags: flutter

How do I enable **shift + return** keys on iOS keyboard to go to a new line in flutter.

```
                                                title: TextFField(
                                                  textCapitalization:
                                                      TextCapitalization
                                                          .sentences,
                                                  key: Key(indx.toString()),
                                                  textInputAction:
                                                      TextInputAction
                                                          .newline,
                                                  keyboardType:
                                                      TextInputType
                                                          .multiline,
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [shortcuts](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html) class in flutter.

```
Shortcuts(
      shortcuts: ...your shortcuts here (shift+return)
      child: Actions(
        actions: <Type, Action<Intent>>{
              \\Create  a class extending an intent and then 
              \\add a \n to the end of your text field.
          ),
        },
```

but I think for your case you can also use (and will be easy)
[SingleActivatorClass](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleActivator-class.html). And when the callback is invoked in that class you can set the text field.